# Manipulating recognized numbers from a numbers recognition script in python

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-learn, scikit-image

I have a workable numbers recognition script in python that works and produces this result[image]

This was created using opencv,sklearn and skimage. How do I how save the recognized image in a file to use later in a different computation?

Comment: Do you want to save the output you are showing above? Or only the parts of image which are recognized as digits? Please be specific

Comment: Only the parts of the image which are recognized as digits

Answer (score 0):

You need to save crops of the original image to separate files. Without seeing your code it is not possible to determine how you are storing the crops, but you need to access the values used for drawing the green rectangles. The same values for drawing the green rectangles can then be used to save a crop of the image by slicing the image.

If you used opencv `cv2.rectangle()` function to draw the boxes it would mean you have the top-left corner and bottom-right corner of the rectangle. However, numpy slicing is in the format:

`crop_image = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]`

Therefore, you would have to compute the height and width values (i.e. `height = (xmax - xmin) + xmin` and the same for width).

Again as you have no code showing my guess is you have a loop that draws the boxes. If that is the case underneath the `cv2.rectange()` function you could write:

```
crop_image = image[ymin: (ymax-ymin)+ymin, xmin: (max-min)+xmin]
cv2.imwrite('images/prediction_'+predicted_value+'_'+count+'.jpg', crop_image)
```

Reference this against your code to get the xmin/xmax/ymin/ymax values:

`cv2.rectange(img, (xmin, ymin), (xmax, ymax), (R, G, B), Thickness)`

Where image is the input image you do the predictions on, predicted_value is the prediction you made for the number and count is a basic count to ensure you don't override files. You can obtain this by using the enumerate function in the for loop: i.e. `for count, x in enumerate(data)`

The output files would save to a folder called images (assuming you've created this prior) and with files name like:

```
prediction_3_0.jpg
prediction_4_1.jpg
prediction_2_2.jpg
prediction_3_3.jpg
prediction_5_4.jpg
```

This way when you read them back in you know what the predicted number was. Let me know if any of my assumptions are wrong and I can edit the answer.

Comment: cv2.imwrite did work but it allows me to save as an image. The goal here is after I recognize the numbers I use it to perform some calculations and saving it as another image wouldn't be ideal.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean here. But do you mean you want to store the crop of the image for further calculations? If so you could just create an empty list at the start of the script i.e. `cropped_images = []` and then instead of `cv2.imwrite('filename.jpg', crop_image)` you could just have `cropped_images.append(crop_image)`. The easiest thing to do then would be convert it into a numpy array with `cropped_images = np.array(cropped_images)` and then you can access any image you want by indexing it.